# suppose $\omega(n)$ denote the number of distinct prime factors of n

Tags: elementary-number-theory, multiplicative-function

Suppose $\omega(n)$ denote the number of distinct prime factors of n. Prove that$$|\mu(n)|=\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)*2^{\omega(n/d)}$$
Can any one give me some hints about this problem? Is $\mu(n)$ a multiplicative function?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $\mu$ is definitely multiplicative.  Consider $\mu(m), \mu(n)$. Look at cases where if either $m$ or $n$ is not square free, then $mn$ is not square free which means $\mu(mn)=0$.  Then suppose both are square free....then $mn$ is also square free.  Now consider their prime decompositions since they are not square free.  This should be enough evidence to tell you it is a multiplicative function.

Comment: thank you!  I get the idea now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be done in three steps. Put
$$g(n) = \sum_{d|n} \mu(d) \times 2^{\omega(n/d)}.$$

The first step is to  note that since $\mu(n)$ and $2^{\omega(n)}$ are
both multiplicative so is $g(n).$

The second step is to apply Moebius inversion to obtain
$$ 2^{\omega(n)} = \sum_{d|n} g(n).$$

The third is to calculate $g(n)$  from this equation. We start with
$n=1$
$$g(1) = 2^{\omega(1)} =  1$$ and continue with $n=p$ where $p$ is a prime 
$$g(1) + g(p) = 2^{\omega(p)}
= 2\quad\text{thus}\quad g(p) = 1.$$

Next is $n=p^2$ which gives
 $$g(1) + g(p) +  g(p^2) = 2$$  so $$g(p^2) = 0.$$

Continuing we  have by induction that  $g(p^v) = 0$ for  $v\ge 2.$ But
since $g$ is  multiplicative this means that $g(n)$ is  zero if $n$ is
not squarefree and one otherwise, which is precisely the defintion of
$|\mu(n)|$ so that $$g(n) = |\mu(n)|$$ which was to be shown.

Comment: By Moebius Inversion, the second step might be $$ 2^{\omega(n)} = \sum_{d|n} g(d).$$

Comment: I am interested in counting  $\sum_{i \le N} |\omega(i)=4|$ . was wondering if you could help.